# Hard Drive Recovery and mounting

Tags: ssd, multi-boot, mount, data-recovery, partition-recovery

I have an internal hard drive(SSD). This drive is not double booted, but triple booted (Windows, Ubuntu, Kali). It is partitioned in such a way that windows has 60% of the drive, and Ubuntu/Kali have 20% respectively. I had the Ubuntu operating system booted on, and was doing a lot of work (lots of data was created (and stored)). When I shut down the operating system (which would quickly write any data that needed to be written to disk before turning off and wiping the RAM). The issue I am facing is I have over written the disk (put too much data into the partition), so it corrupted the partitions and the grub boot loader no longer appears at boot time. Now the system doesn't boot at all (except for rare occurences when it detects the Windows an automatically boots into it).
Notes: the partition is not working because it has too much data stored on it.
I canot get the partitions to mount from a live disk (unless someone knows how I can do that).
When in windows I used the disk management console to view the partitions and saw that it marked Ubuntu, and Kali, as being 100% space (even though they aren't 100% free in fact Ubuntu should be 105% used (i.e. too much storage))
How can I recover the personal data off this drive. Or how can I get this drive to mount using a live USB disk, so that I can access the contents (I've had to do some work prior to this to recover partitions like this in the past). If I can get it to mount I can probably get it working.
Any suggestions are greatly appreciated: will upvote and accept answer that leads to most learning/success.

Comment: The volume of data on the drive does not prevent it from mounting. Your drive is actually failing, not just too full.

Comment: @music2myear Okay I will try to see the process on recovering that. Thanks

Comment: _"I have over written the disk (put too much data into the partition)"_, _"in fact Ubuntu should be 105% used (i.e. too much storage)"_ - this isn't possible. Filesystems don't extend past partition boundaries. You can't have more than 100% of data on a partition, just like you can't fill a bottle more than full. Check drive's SMART attributes and [edit] them in. Boot Ubuntu from USB and show us a screenshot from GParted. Don't trust Windows's _Disk Management_ with Linux partitions.